# MS ACCESS join on like

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

Lets say I have Two tables, Skus and Tradenames.

SKU

```
+-------+-------------+
|  SKU  | Description |
+-------+-------------+
| D1234 | Circle Red  |
| D1235 | Circle Blue |
| D1236 | Square Red  |
| D1237 | Square Blue |
+-------+-------------+
```

Tradenames

```
+-----------+-------------------+
| Tradename |  Product Manual   |
+-----------+-------------------+
| Circle    | All about circles |
| Square    | Squares 101       |
+-----------+-------------------+
```

And i want

```
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+
|  Sku  | Description | Tradename |      Manual       |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+
| D1234 | Circle Red  | Circle    | All about Circles |
| D1235 | Circle Blue | Circle    | All about Circles |
| D1236 | Square Red  | Square    | Squares 101       |
| D1237 | Square Blue | Square    | Squares 101       |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

but there is no actual identifier between them that is the exact same.
Is there a way to join a table using LIKE??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like` or `instr()`:

```
select sku.*, tn.tradename, tn.manual
from sku join
     tradenames as tn
     on instr(sku.description, tn.tradename) > 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `LIKE` here:

```
SELECT
    s.SKU,
    s.Description,
    t.Tradename,
    t.Manual
FROM SKU s
INNER JOIN Tradenames t
    ON s.Description LIKE "*" & t.Tradename & "*";
```